# MAMP on MacOS 11.2.1 Disfunctional - RESOLVED

Tags: macos, mamp

Have MAMP 6.3 on an updated macOS 11.2.1

The Configuration popup launches

Web server is working but that is it.

MySQL is not running although indicates Server is 5.7.32

Ports 80 and 30036 or 8888 makes no difference

http://localhost:8888/MAMP ... unable to connect

http://localhost:8888/MAMP/phpmyadmin.php ... unable to connect

Seems like I'm the only one for some reason as doesn't seem to anything I can find

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing all log files inside of the MAMP/db/mysql directory and restart MAMP.
I'm also using the same MAMP and macOS version as you but it's working.

Comment: You are a saint.
So simple been chasing this for a couple of days
Thanks so much

Comment: Enjoy! Be sure to mark it as a working answer so people with the same issue are able to quickly find a solution :)